# Bars not showing up in grouped bar chart

Tags: d3.js

I'm trying to create a grouped bar chart showing students attenadance(present or absent) but for some reasons my chart is showing only one set of bars(the highest for present and the highest for absent. On inspecting the console I see that the remaining bars are there but they are not showing up on the chart. I don't know if the problem is with my data or my code(I have only included the js part of the code)

```
const SVG = {
    height: 900,
    width: 900
}
const margin = {top: 40, bottom: 40, right: 40, left: 40};
const innerWidth = SVG.width - margin.left - margin.right;
const innerHeight = SVG.height - margin.top - margin.bottom;

const bar = d3.select('body').append('svg').attr('width', SVG.width).attr('height', SVG.height);
const grp = bar.append('g').attr('transform', `translate(${margin.left}, ${margin.top})`);

const data = d3.csv('WEEK.csv')
.then(
function(data) {
console.log(data);
const keys = data.columns.slice(1);
console.log(keys)
const group = d3.map(data, function(d){return +d.Week}).keys()
const x0 = d3.scaleBand().domain(group)
                            .range([0, innerWidth]).padding(0.1)
const x1 = d3.scaleBand().domain(keys)
                            .range([0, x0.bandwidth()]).padding(0.05)
const y0 = d3.scaleLinear().domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) {return d3.max(keys, function (key){return +d[key];} 
                            )})])
                        .range([innerHeight, 0]);
const color = d3.scaleOrdinal().range('#fcba03', '#eb4034')
const yAxis = d3.axisLeft(y0);
const xAxis = d3.axisBottom(x0);

const yAxisG = grp.append('g').call(yAxis)
const xAxisG = grp.append('g').call(xAxis)
        .attr('transform', `translate(0, ${innerHeight})`);
    
 grp.append('g')
    .selectAll('g')
    .data(data)
    .enter().append('g')
    .selectAll('rect')
        .attr("transform", function(d) {return "translate(" + x0(+d.Week) + ",0)"})
    .data(function(d){return keys.map(function(key){return{key: key, value: +d[key]} }) })
    .enter()
    .append('rect')
        .attr('width', x1.bandwidth())
        .attr('height', d => (innerHeight - y0(d.value)))
        .attr('y', d => y0(d.value))
        .attr('x', d => x1(d.key))
        .attr('fill', d => color(d.key));  
})
```

The dataset:
Week ,Present,Absent
2,10481,4010
3,11277,4551
4,10499,5036
5,9970,5126
6,8901,4909
7,7929,8405
8,7995,5062
9,7785,5447
10,7670,5822
11,7177,6162
12,6258,6499
13,4689,6631

Comment: I think you need to append another `rect` for the second series

Comment: All the examples I saw online only appended once, where would I append the second one?